# How do I fix the 403 error for wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?

Tags: wp-admin, errors

When I use the Safari console, I always get the following notification:

> failed to load the resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   for wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've already checked the file permissions. These work out fine so far.

Comment: What URL are you requesting to and from (the whole URLs, please)? Is it a custom ajax request from your JS code, for instance? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try a reinstall of WP (via Admin, Updates) to ensure all WP files are where they are supposed to be.